# Customize Next and Back button Callbacks for jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, jcarousel

I have implemented jCarousel to show 4 visible image from the list of images.

On load of jcarousel, first image is highlighted. When user clicks the other image, it gets highlighted. Please check the demo html.

I am struggling do add below functionality.

- On click of Next Or Previous button, First visible image in the carousel should be highlighted. I am unable to get the visible image in the list.

Please Find below test html with jquery code.

Thanks in Advance..!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script> 
<style>
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
    background: #F0F6F9;
    border: 1px solid #346F97;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 335px;
    padding: 20px 40px;

}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical {
    width: 75px;
    height: 245px;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width: 335px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url(http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/next-horizontal.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-next-horizontal {
    left: 5px;
    right: auto;
    background-image: url(http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/prev-horizontal.png);
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:focus {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal:active {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:focus,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal:active {
    cursor: default;
    background-position: -96px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url(http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/prev-horizontal.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl .jcarousel-prev-horizontal {
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
    background-image: url(next-horizontal.png);
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:hover, 
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:focus {
    background-position: -32px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal:active {
    background-position: -64px 0;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:hover,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:focus,
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal:active {
    cursor: default;
    background-position: -96px 0;
}
</style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 0;
            function nextCall(carousel, button, enabled) {              
                console.log('nextCall '+i, enabled);            
            }

            function prevCall(carousel, button, enabled) {          
                console.log('prevCall '+i, enabled);            
            }

 jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll:2,   
        animation:'slow',   
        initCallback:function(){
             $("#mycarousel li:eq(0)").css('border','3px solid green');
            }
        ,
        buttonNextCallback:   nextCall,
        buttonPrevCallback:   prevCall  
     });
     $("#mycarousel li").click(function(){
         $("#mycarousel li").css('border','none');
         $(this).css('border','3px solid green');
     });     
     });
</script>
<title>Smart JCarousel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab-container">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create one simple fiddle...!!

Comment: some technical problem :( You can use this working html. n Tell me if any problem you face.